# Can i change the language of android app?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am developing news application for Gujarati Language.
Now my problem is that its working well but it shows Squares([]) instead of fonts, so how can i make it visible in Gujarati language so it can display Gujarati fonts .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have the font file for gujarati?

Answer (score 4):

First of all copy font in assets folder, then write

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/gujaratifont.otf");
```

and then :

```
text.setTypeFace(tf);
```

Comment: Yea both otf and ttf can be used.

Comment: I tried this but its not giving proper output it still shows me squares.

Comment: insertData("3","hello.jpg","'સુપર ફાઇટ લીગ' ના આગામી ઉદ્ઘાટન સમારોહમાં 'અનારકલી' ધમાલ મચાવશે ","This is the third item");

TextView cap = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.caption);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/gujaratifont.ttf");
  cap.setTypeface(tf);

Comment: If this does not work Save it in String.xml file. like <string name="guj">'સુપર ફાઇટ લીગ' ના આગામી ઉદ્ઘાટન સમારોહમાં 'અનારકલી' ધમાલ મચાવશે</string>

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to change the font typeface using xml.

1. Define a new NameSpace: `xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.nound.test"` (“com.nound.test” is the package name defined in Manifest.xml)
2. Define the custom attribute(s) in /res/values/attrs.xml file.

   ```
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="TypefacedTextView">
            <attr name="textStyle" format="string"/>
       </declare-styleable> </resources>
   ```
3. Java class that extends TextView... as follows
   public class TypefacedTextView extends TextView {

   ```
   public TypefacedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);

       //Typeface.createFromAsset doesn't work in the layout editor. Skipping...
       if (isInEditMode()) {
           return;
       }

       TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TypefacedTextView);
       //String fontName = styledAttrs.getString(R.styleable.TypefacedTextView_typeface);
       String fontNameForBold = styledAttrs.getString(R.styleable.TypefacedTextView_textStyle);
       styledAttrs.recycle();

       if (fontNameForBold!=null && fontNameForBold.equals("bold")) {
           Typeface typeface_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/tahoma/tahoma_bold.ttf");
           setTypeface(typeface_bold);
       }else{
           Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/tahoma/tahoma.ttf");
           setTypeface(typeface);
       }
   }
   ```
4. here is the layout code where you wanna change the font typeface. in this "com.nound.test.ui" is the above (3 point) java file package name. 
   TypefacedTextView is class name.

> ```
> <com.nound.test.ui.TypefacedTextView
>             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.nound.test"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Custom fonts in XML are easy_bold font"
>             your_namespace:textStyle="bold" />
>
>
> <com.nound.test.ui.TypefacedTextView
>             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.nound.test"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Custom fonts in XML are easy_regular font"
>             />
> ```

its enough to do...